# Winamp Error "Stopped working" - Exception Code 0xc0000005 - module name: unknown

Tags: windows-7, crash, winamp

I decided to upgrade a working Winamp installation to the latest version but now it crashes right after loading the main window.

I've tried resetting plugins and winamp.ini to no avail.

I'm running Windows 7 64-bit with onboard sound (Asus P5K SE) and a Radeon 5450.

Here's the log from event viewer:

```
Faulting application name: winamp.exe, version: 5.6.2.3173, time stamp: 0x4e1b6f92
Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00705c68
Faulting process id: 0x24d4
Faulting application start time: 0x01cc6763e7749a19
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Winamp\winamp.exe
Faulting module path: unknown
Report Id: 275c5fef-d357-11e0-9075-00158315a310
```

I tried an older version as well:

```
Faulting application name: winamp.exe, version: 5.6.0.3085, time stamp: 0x4cf7c203
Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0072b118
Faulting process id: 0x1eb8
Faulting application start time: 0x01cc67644d719405
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Winamp\winamp.exe
Faulting module path: unknown
Report Id: 91b1a0b5-d357-11e0-9075-00158315a310
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so i thought i had disabled the old plugins but haven't. The problem was with gen_mp3cue.dll. Now everything is back to normal.

I was sorting the plugin folder by date to remove the old ones, but for some reason winamp reset the date of all plugins. So i did a clean install and winamp worked. So I started placing the old plugins one by one until winamp crashed, right after i placed gen_mp3cue.dll

Comment: You might add some detail to your answer as to what you did to fix the error.